# External display not detected correctly in Dell Latitude E6530

Tags: 13.04, external-monitor

Currently, I bought the laptop [Dell Latitude E6530](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Latitude#Current_models) and installed Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit (Raring Ringtail) alongside with Windows 7 (I could not get rid of it because of some special programs for work).

Ubuntu worked well. However, it did not detect the external displays (Dell 23" and Dell 19") no matter if I plugged them in before or after booting.

I connected my laptop to those external displays through a laptop dock.

[image]

I went to *Settings* -> *Display*. The displays were there, but when I enabled them, Ubuntu logged off automatically. No external display was detected. In addition, the laptop screen sometimes was detected as Dell 23".

I got advice from similar topic that the [Nvidia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia) driver should be updated to version 313 or 319. I upgraded the driver and the [Unity Launcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29#User_interface) disappeared, main display resolution turned to 640*480 and none of the external displays were detected.

I tried to use additional drivers, but when I turned it on, it told me that there was no driver to be used.

What should I do?

I have set options `vmwgfx enable_fbdev=1`.

Comment: Did you try fully uninstalling the prior nVidia drivers before updating to the new ones? Try issuing `nvidia-installer --uninsall` to do a full installation. After this, make sure you are using the original /etc/X11/Xorg.conf file that was in place before the original nVidia driver installation (the installer usually backs them up in sequence if I remember correctly). Then, attempt to re-install the newer nVidia drivers.

Comment: Also worth noting: I had issues on my ATI card (also using proprietary drivers) and external displays. I had to tweak something in the ATI control panel that allowed me to use the built-in Control Panel to set up my displays. The setting that I had to disable was the setting to use Xinerama. Even then, it took a lot of fiddling to get it to work properly. Take this with a grain of salt though, it's an apples-to-oranges comparison

Comment: I uninstalled but there was no Xorg.conf file there. The situation turned to upgrading situation, which I described before.

Comment: Hmm... so this was after uninstalling the original driver or did you just uninstall the one you had?

Comment: the original driver is Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile. I don't know how to remove or upgrade it :(

Comment: Hmmm. Even the Ivy Bridge graphics should be good enough to run a normal display in Unity/Gnome Shell/whatever. Could you perhaps update your question with the contents of /etc/modprobe/modprobe.conf or any files in /etc/modprobe that look like they may related to graphics such as noveau.conf intel.conf or similar?

Comment: There is no modeprobe directory in etc. What I can find is a folder named "modeprobe.d". Howerver, there is no similar name of file like you suggested. Most of the file names started with blacklist. I updated with the content of a suspicious file name "vmwgfx-fbdev.conf". The other file, which doesn't start with blacklist is : "# mlx4_core gets automatically loaded, load mlx4_en also (LP: #1115710)
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en"

Comment: If you have Nvidia Optimus, you will need this http://bumblebee-project.org/

Comment: did you try the xorg-edgers PPA? https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling Optimus in the BIOS? I had this issue as well with an E6530. I had to re-enable Optimus when booting Windows again, otherwise I had issues with wireless (I'm not sure if this was required though)